# Handling Instagram Embedded Browser Traffic for Self-Referencing Links

Tags: redirect, instagram, wkwebview

I'm facing an issue within Instagram's mobile app. I have a website with a URL that links to an Instagram account's direct messages. When users click this link within Instagram's embedded view, instead of smoothly navigating to the app, the view attempts to load a browser version of Instagram, resulting in a broken link that leaves users stranded on a non-functional direct message skeleton page.

I'm seeking a solution to address this problem. My ideal outcome is for the embedded view to gracefully close and guide users to their Instagram direct messages, mirroring the behavior in external mobile browsers.

The URL 'https://ig.me/m/' functions correctly in all browsers except when accessed within Instagram's embedded view. While this behavior aligns with Instagram's strategy of retaining users within their app, an issue arises specifically within the embedded view, potentially linked to direct message URLs.